# How do you add a link in an f string?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to add a link in the f string below:

```
d += f'<li> {event.time} {event.teacher} {event.student} {event.status} </li>'
```

Basically, I want it to look something like below:

```
f'<li> <a href="{% url 'somewhere' event.pk %}"> {event.time} {event.teacher} {event.student} {event.status} </a> </li>'
```

However, I get the following error when I do this:

```
SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'
```

Do you guys know how to input a link in an f string? Please ask me any questions you have.

Here is the context of the code where I have the f-string as some of you asked:

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        events_per_day = events.filter(date__day=day)
        d = ''
        if True:
            for event in events_per_day:
                d += f'<li> {event.time} {event.teacher} {event.student} {event.status} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'
```

By the way, this is all in my utils.py folder.

Comment: Please give more information as to where the f-string would be placed....thanks.Would it be directly in a view or in a message object within a view

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the context for the f string in the question.

Comment: The code looks OK to me. Is the problem with some other (accidentally mangled) f-string in your code? Check the line number associated with the error message.

Comment: By the way, you probably want to be returning `mark_safe( f"<td>...</td>")` which might solve your next problem. Provided it IS safe, that is. `format_html` is usually preferable in contexts like this.

Comment: I actually tried `<a href='somewhere' event.pk>` instead of the one with the brackets written above, and it had no error. However, the link doesn't work at all when I try to click it in the webpage.

Comment: I'm guessing I may have answered your last comment before you posted it. Look at the source code of your page, that link in particular. Had Django escaped part of it?

Comment: No, I think its there without anything missing out. Interestingly, when I do `<a href='profile'>` for the link, the word "profile" is added to the end of the current link. Of course, since I don't have such a url, I get an error message. Would this be of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An f-string does will not evaluate Django template tags, it just sees this as curly brackets, but where the content happens to be a non-sensical expression.

You can make use of [**`reverse(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to perform URL pattern resolution:

```
from django.urls import reverse

f'<li> <a href="{ reverse("somewhere", args=(event.pk,)) }"> {event.time} {event.teacher} {event.student} {event.status} </a> </li>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I get `SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('`. Do you know why?

Comment: @codebuilder: are you sulre you opened the parenthesis at `args=(`? I've tested it with the given expression, and that worked. The parenthesis in the expression should be balanced.

Comment: @codebuilder: you thus need to close *two* parenthesis, one for the singleton tuple, and one for the function call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use variable to achieve the same output :-

```
url_endpoint = reverse("somewhere", args=(event.pk,))

f'<li> <a href="{url_endpoint}"> {event.time} {event.teacher} {event.student} {event.status} </a> </li>'
```